How does a jhipster-generated gateway uses hazelcast?
I plan to implement a brute-force prevention service in the gateway that saves the IPs with failed attempts into Hazelcast. However, I cannot find how Hazelcast is configured.
I chose Hazelcast as the cache and read in the documentation that Hazelcast is the default cache for gateways for rate-limiting. However, I cannot find the RateLimitingFilter, CacheConfiguration, or a Hazelcast Management Center docker-compose file anywhere.
Should I configure it the same way as it is done in other microservices?
Here are my jhipster generation settings:
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "gateway",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "newFolder",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    **"cacheProvider": "hazelcast",**
    "clientFramework": "angular",
    "clientTestFrameworks": [],
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "creationTimestamp": 1717163178963,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    **"enableHibernateCache": true,**
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": false,
......
}


The same here! .....
